# How do you quickly determine which coefficients are greater than zero when multiplying two univariate positive polynomials?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that I have two polynomials with a degree of $n$, $A(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0$ and $B(x) = b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + b_0$ and the coefficients of these polynomials are zero or greater. Suppose I multiply $A(X)$ and $B(x)$, $C(x) = A(x)B(x)$.

For the polynomial $C(x)$, how do I determine if the term $c_i$ is zero or greater? What is the fastest algorithm for determining whether for all terms $c_i$ if it is zero or nonzero?

Comment: I m sorry, I am slow and do not get your question. If $A$ and $B$ have positive coefficients, then so does $C$... What are you not telling me?

Comment: $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ only consists of coefficients that are either zero and greater than zero. For example, let $A(x) = x^ 2$ and $B(x) = x^2 + 1$. As a result, $A(x) B(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$. We notice from this result that the coefficents that are zero are terms $x^3$ and $x$. I was wondering if there is there is a fast polynomial, possibly faster than $O(nlogn)$, to compute the coefficients that would be zero.

Comment: Well, there is an obvious linear-time ($O(i)$) algorithm: $c_i=0$ if and only if for each $j\le i$, $a_j=0$ or $b_{i-j}=0$. Since the answer depends on all these coefficients, you have at least to read them, hence you cannot make it significantly faster.

Comment: It may be easier to write the question as follows: let $A, B$ be finite sets of nonnegative integers; is there a fast way to determine $C = \{a + b|a \in A, b \in B\}$? This is equivalent, by making $A$ the set of nonzero coefficients of $A(x)$, and similarly for $B,C$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think mtber75 is looking for an algorithm to cover all of the $c_i$ at once, not one at a time. In that case, the naive algorithm takes $O(n^2)$

Comment: @mtber75: thank you. I was mislead by the fact that you used the expression "zero or greater" twice in different context. I hope you do not mind my edit.

Comment: I think there should be a reduction from inner product to your problem which will give it a linear lower bound in log bound memory model.

Comment: @user44191 Well, I missed that the OP asked two questions, and only answered the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Since polynomial multiplication is essentially (non-cyclic) convolution, and for *arbitrary* polynomials $A(x),B(x)$, the fastest known convolution algorithms (based on the fast fourier transform) have complexity $O(d \log d)$ where $d=\max\{\deg A,\deg B\},$ without assumptions on the structure of the zero coefficients of $A$ and $B,$ there can't be a faster algorithm without any breakthroughs in algorithms computing convolutions.

**Edit:** In the light of the comments, I now realize that it is correct one does not need to compute the full convolution. Modeling the nonzero coefficients of $A,B$ as subsets $S_A,S_B,$ of $\{1,\ldots,d\}$ the question can be related to computing properties of the sumset $S_A+S_B\subset \{1,2,\ldots,2d\}.$

It seems to me that in general this can be done in time $w_A w_B$ in the worst case where $w_A=\# S_A,$ is the *weight* (no. of nonzero coefficients) of the polynomial or the cardinality of $S_A,$ etc. So certainly, if $w_A w_B <d \log d,$ this would give an improvement.

If the specific coefficient was $c_i,$ and we were only interested in whether $c_i$ was zero, then one would only need to consider the sets $S_A \cap \{0,1,2,\ldots,c_i\}$ and $S_b \cap \{0,1,2,\ldots c_i\}$ and by scanning forward in one and backward in the other set, while looking for two terms which sum to $c_i,$ one could actually determine if $c_i$ was nonzero or not in $O(c_i)$ time.

Comment: But you are not actually computing the convolution.